# Liferay p_auth correlation

Tags: jmeter

In my application the value of p_auth is dynamically changes 
I tried to handle it by correlation and it seems fine to me but not getting succeed.

I am attaching some screenshots , Please help me to identify where I am wrong

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsbGi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECUle.png)

Comment: This is result from debug sampler as well JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=true
JMeterThread.pack=org.apache.jmeter.threads.SamplePackage@18f0f0d
START.HMS=111431
START.MS=1462772671090
START.YMD=20160509
TESTSTART.MS=1462786530853
authToken=HPMLVZeI
authToken_g=1
authToken_g0=p_auth=HPMLVZeI&
authToken_g1=HPMLVZeI
formdate=1462786577964
formdate_g=1
formdate_g0=name="_mylead_WAR_myleadportlet_formDate" type="hidden" value="1462786577964"
formdate_g1=1462786577964

Answer (score 0):

P_AUTH is Liferay [authentication token](https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Authentication+Token) which is used for [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) protection, it can be handled in 3 easy steps:

Design your test scenario as follows:

1. Open login page
2. Extract `p_auth`
3. Pass extracted values from step 2 into login request

Step 2 in details:

If you look into response text from step 1 you will see `p_auth` in the response body:

[image: P_AUTH]

In order to extract it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the 1st request and configure it as follows:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `p_auth`
- Regular Expression: `p_auth=(.+?)"`
- Template: $1$

Usually it is not required to extract `formDate` parameter, I usually substitute it with [${__time(,)} function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time)

So request itself looks like:

[image: Request Details]

To double check we have successfully logged in - check out Response Data tab of the last request which opens user dashboard:

[image: Verify Login]

See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) article for a little bit more detailed information on bypassing CSRF protection in JMeter tests.

---

P.S. I see [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECUle.png). If it is something you got during recording - **REMOVE IT** as it can contain hard-coded irrelevant headers which may harm or at least review headers and leave (or correlate) only those you need